# android_alarm_manager_plus not triggering after reboot

Tags: android, flutter

I'm having trouble with triggering periodic alarms after reboot. They trigger fine while the phone is running but not after reboot. Upon further investigation, it seems that the alarms are actually being set after the reboot, but the app is not triggering. This is from logcat:

```
07-25 13:54:04.631  1709  2139 I ActivityManager: Start proc 14309:xxx/u0a554 for service {xxx/dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService}
07-25 13:55:31.770  1709  2612 W AlarmManager: Alarms must either supply a PendingIntent or an AlarmReceiver
```